# In Access 2007, how can I change the *Design View* tab order of controls..?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

There's an ocean of web pages that explain how to change the tab order of Access 2007 form controls as they function in ***Form View***. But...can the tab order of controls be changed as they function in ***Design View***..?

I'm a keyboard freak and prefer to tab through controls in Design View, and to use the keyboard as much as possible to adjust control properties. But on complex forms with many controls, the lack of an obvious tab order can get annoying. I'm currently working on a form with over 50 controls, and if I could tab through them in ***any*** kind of recognizable order, it would be most appreciated.

Comment: by default order of creation, if you have any layout, then order of arrangement. I'd suggest getting used to mice :) especially the scroll wheel is very handy :) :)

Comment: Ugh. Sounds like its time for some Digital Decon mouse killer. Alternatively, I could become acquainted with the format of the design file behind the form, which can be accessed through the hidden & undocumented method `Access.Application.SaveAsText'...and re-order them manually. =-)

Comment: I would second krish's suggestion. Access is very mouse-centric. Although, writing a script to re-order the Access.Application.SaveAsText output is an intriguing idea...